# Filters for feature map in convolutional neural network

Tags: filter, neural-network, convolution, feature-extraction, conv-neural-network

What kind of filter should I use to extract feature maps in convolutional NN?

I been reading about convolutional NN recently and I understood that we use **a set of filters to generate a set of feature maps** in each convolution layer by convoluting those filters over outputs from the previous layer.

1)How do we get these filters?

2)Do we pick filters randomly and do some 'trial and error'?

3)How do we find perfect filters for our project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You don't directly get it, you let the network get it by showing some examples (training data)

2) We do initialise the filters randomly so that they can learn something useful and different to each.

3) By providing lots of data that are relevant to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks are trained using backpropagation algorithm, you can get familiar with it [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html). Simply saying it computes the derivatives of the weights(filter values in your case) with respect to the loss function which measures the perfomance of the network. The backpropagation algorithm is a bit ore complicated for convolutional neural networks, but it's still intuitive.